# Insertion sort with time complexity of O(nlogn)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, insertion-sort

If we use a binary insertion sort with a balanced binary tree, is the time complexity O(nlogn)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the balanced binary tree is used within the algorithm?